# Adding configurable product to the cart by SKU - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am playing with programatic cart recreation. There is no problem of adding products to cart by id i.e.

```
 $params = array(
    'product' => 272,
    'super_attribute' => array(
        22 =>30 ,
    ),
    'qty' => 2,
);


$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load(272); 
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save(); 
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

But how to do it if I know only product sku, I mean how to get product id and super_attributes for configurable products.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','$sku');
```

seems to return only that product (sku) info and no special_attribute.

Any ideas?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve the product by getting a collection, filtered by the SKU:

```
$searchForThisSku = 'p_1234';

/** @var $productCollection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$productCollection = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter( 'sku', $searchForThisSku );

/** @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
$product = $productCollection->getFirstItem();

// you should have the product now, maybe it isn't even necessary to get the ID
$product->getId();

// all in one line:
$productId = (int) Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter( 'sku', $searchForThisSku )
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getId();
```

Comment: almost there, looks like I am loosing size/color on checkout display when added this way despite proper sku, could be internal issue...

Comment: hmm I don't know how to include super_attribute now, looks like lack of them is a cause

Comment: If you did not see all product attributes, you probably have to load its contents from the database: `$product->load( $product->getId() );`

Answer (score 3):

i think, [feeela](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509191/790879) didn't answer the question.

general (without error-handling):

```
$sku = 'any-sku-number';
$qty = 1;

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

$parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());

$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(current($parentIds));

if ($parent->getTypeId() === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $paramsSuperAttribute = array('super_attribute' => array());

    foreach ($parent->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($parent) as $attribute) {
        $paramsSuperAttribute['super_attribute'][$attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeId()] =
            (int) $product->getData($attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
    }
}

$params = array('qty' => $qty);
```

now, there are two ways adding a product to cart by sku:

programmatically:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$cart->addProduct(isset($parent) ? $parent : $product, array_merge($params, $paramsSuperAttribute))->save();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

by url:

```
$addToCartUrl = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')
    ->getAddUrl(isset($parent) ? $parent : $product, $params);

if (isset($parent)) {
    $addToCartUrl .= '?' . http_build_query($paramsSuperAttribute);
}

// now you can use this url like this (controller action)
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($addToCartUrl);
return;
```

Comment: This should have been chosen as the answer, it helped me understand better how to get the right attribute value, thanks a lot Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/** @product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$sku = 'sku';
$product->load($sku, 'sku');
```